# How to get text content from HTML STRING CONTENT and to share it through all means?

Tags: android, html, xml

I have used HTML STRING CONTENT as a WEBVIEW in the App. The Code for HTML STRING CONTENT written as:

```
text = "<html><body>" +
 "<p align=\"justify\">"+ 
getString(R.string.hadesc1)+
"</p>"+<p align=\"justify\">"+
getString(R.string.hadesc2)+"</p>"+
"<p align=\"justify\"><b>"+
getString(R.string.hadesc3)</b>/p>"+
"<p align=\"justify\">"+
getString(R.string.hadesc4)+
"</p>"+"<p align=\"justify\"><b>"
+getString(R.string.hadesc5)+
"</b></p><dl>"+"<dt align=\"justify\"><b><u>"
+getString(R.string.hadesc7)+"</u></b></dt>"+
 "<dd align=\"justify\">"+
 getString(R.string.hadesc8)+"</dd>"
```

And I am using it in

```
mWebView.loadData(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);`
```

But, I want to share only text from this above data.So,
I have written the code as like this,

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");                
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(text));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share Via:"));
```

But, it shares only for emails.
I need to share by Bluetooth, Facebook, mails and messaging. So, Kindly please help what I need to do.

Comment: When I run the `Intent` it works nicely, could you add the code, where you call the `Intent` to share?

Comment: Actually, I need to share using **Facebook,Bluetooth,SMS-messaging**, But the above code provide me to share only through e-mails.

Comment: Yes,when click it display all sharing means such as fcaebook, bluetooth and sms-Messaging  but the content extraction is done and displays only in e-mails. Actually, I need to share using **Facebook,Bluetooth,SMS-messaging**, But the above code provide me to share only through e-mails. So,please help me if there any Method to write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've tried the code together with your `HTML` from the `String`...

It seems that the `String` `text` can't be converted to `HTML` and so the conversion "silently" fails with a warning in the LogCat saying:

```
04-16 23:44:40.527: W/Bundle(1983): Key android.intent.extra.TEXT expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString.  The default value <null> was returned.
04-16 23:44:40.527: W/Bundle(1983): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
04-16 23:44:40.527: W/Bundle(1983): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The method `Html.fromHtml(text)` returns a `SpannableString` and this in turn can't be put inside the `ShareIntent`.

So if you explicitly call `toString()` on the returned `Spannable` it will work.

So the line should look like this:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(text).toString());
```

On a side-note: your `HTML` isn't valid, so it might not return anything useful at all, but now it can be sent anyways.